# notion api missing property value

Tags: api, notion-api

This is a problem that occurred during the process of retrieving the value of the database by using notion API.

The communication is successful, so the json data is being parsed, but there is a problem that the value of the property entered in the nootion DB is not loaded.

When testing using Postman, the name of the property is reflected as follows, but only the ID is entered.

```
 "properties": {
                "Tag": {
                    "id": "%60fit"
                },
                "My property": {
                    "id": "ks%40t"
                },
                "Name": {
                    "id": "title"
                }
            },
```

What are some ways to think about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like it's a problem with latest version of notion client, I was able to solve this by downgrading to `"@notionhq/client": "^0.4.4",`

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I changed the Notion version information of the request header to the previous version, referring to what you said, and it was solved.

Comment: Which version to use?

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me :) I've set my CURL request with this version : "Notion-Version: 2022-02-22"

Answer (score 5):

As of [v2.0.0](https://developers.notion.com/changelog/releasing-notion-version-2022-06-28), Notion's API doesn't include properties anymore, they made a new dedicated endpoint.

The last property-compatible version was v1.0.4